# How to fix warped orthographic views in 2.8

Tags: orthographic

I recently started practice face modeling, something simple, and I use an image reference because later on I’ll be doing full body models. However, I have an issue with the views in blender. Below is my model, one part in orthographic, and the two images on the sides in perspective. Is there a way to fix this in preferences? I’ve been getting a lot of results saying to change to viewport focal length, and when I attempt that, it only seems to work in the camera and not the entire workspace
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). What *exactly* is the problem and what *exactly* do you want to achieve?

Comment: When in Ortho there is no warping at all. Can you show what you see as deformed in Ortho? (as Jachym asked)?

Comment: Does it correct you mean - How to make perspective type less deformed (look more like ortho)? If so, would be better to edit your question. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this? Ortho in each editor?

[image]

- press Num 5 (switch persp/ortho) in each view
- for Camera view you have to select Camera and go into Properties editor > **Camera Data > Lens** and switch to Orthographic type

[image]

Alternatively you can disable **Auto switch** (persp/ortho) under *User Preferences > Navigation* that keeps set view type.

[image]

---

### Edit

To make Perspective view less deformed **change Focal lenght** in *3D view editor Properties (N)> *View* to something like 200.

[image]

Comment: Not exactly that either. When I use an image reference, and model in blender, I’ve seen orthographic view work for some people when they model, yet when I attempt to do it, and then it switched back to perspective, the model looks weird, and I wanna know if it’s possible to model in orthographic and not have it look weird in perspective

Comment: So I actually did try the auto Perspective, and yes, it actually works better for me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> on your keyboard while having your viewport selected.

Comment: I do that, and it looks fine in that view. I’m just wondering if there’s any way to make the orthographic view not as warped or silly, I’ve seen speed models online of other people being able to work in orthographic just fine without warping models